# Implementing rooted trees with arbitray number of leaves

Tags: algorithm, tree

Let's say the number is given at run-time, eg. 20. Trees are also not necessarily full. Unfortunately reducing the number of leaves doesn't seem to be an option either, as the structure of the tree perserves some physical meaning.

Memory efficiency seems to be a big issue for nodes with more than 1 child. If the memory for the child pointer array has to be reserved/allocated, then a lot of unused memory might be reserved; If using an dynamic array/vector to save the pointers, it's slow when reallocation happens.

So my question is, is there a data structure to perserve the relative parent-child relation while not using a tree with high number of leaves?

Comment: Usually there's a dynamic array for child pointers, and that 'slow when reallocation happens' assertion is not meaningfully true, given that you have to allocate a node anyway.  Other considerations that you haven't mentioned might change that array into an intrusive linked list in some circumstances.

Comment: I was thinking that, for example if the pointers to all children nodes are saved in a vector; if we reserve space for the vector large enough when the branch is full, then it reserves memory that may not be used if the branch is unlikely to be full; if we don't, then if we add a child to the parent and the vector might have to be moved to another memory space

Comment: You add a child and the vector has to be moved to another memory space... so what?

Comment: It's probably slow and create a lot of fragments the memory, imagine a 10 level 20nary tree with every possible nodes evaluated, added/removed as fast as possible

Comment: But you already spent the time to allocate all the child nodes. Is the cost of parent array allocation really large in comparison to that?